# How to store the encryption keys securely in php code file

Tags: php, security, rijndael

I have a website that users submit sensitive data to it then a php script encrypts these sensitive data using rijndael 256 and store it in mysql database

the problem is that I want to store the key in a secure place that can be accessed only by the php script and not to be seen by any other one

Comment: well you could use encrypter/decrypter classes but then its just as easy for an app developer to use the decrypter class on the string. I'm looking forward to the answer from a Security expert.

Comment: where is the php script going to get the key from if no person can see the key?

Comment: yes i want to hide the keys from the programmer, I want the php script is the only who is able to access the key the php script will get the key from another server

Comment: Assuming only admin(s) will need access to your sensitive data, would it be possible to store the private key on a USB drive and make them send the file when the data needs to be decrypted?

Comment: no it's not possible store the private key on a USB drive

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the nature of the sensitive data and who would need access to it and why

Comment: you don't need to know the nature of the sensitive data and the php script needs access to it

Comment: If the 'programmer' has access to the script, then it is impossible for the script to hide the keys from the programmer. All they'd have to do is `echo $key` and you're finished. What you want is impossible.

Comment: If you can't trust the programmer you've got bigger problems.

Comment: If you don't trust your programmers, fire them. Having an untrusted developer can cause all kinds of problems - you never know if he put a backdoor or a little time-bomb somewhere. Even if you review the code, it's possible that something gets through - especially in a language like PHP where you can easily make a security hole look like crappy code.

Comment: Don't forget that the system administrator can simply `ptrace(2)` your process and read keys and sensitive data straight out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how high a security you need for the data. You could consider having a different security key for each user, by possibly encrypting the data that identifies that particular customer and attaching it onto the 256-bit encrypted key. But better still would be split the key up and insert that encrypted data throughout the key. Makes it more complex to decipher. This would mean if a programmer has access to the key the programmer can't simply decrypt everyones data without having access to the customer encrypted data as well which would be different for every user.

And yes it is true that the programmer can still echo the key out to the screen but they would ALSO need the customer encrypted data for each customer they want to decrypt the data of.

You could also consider Public and Private Key Encryption instead if applicable. The customer/user could generate their own keys. Customer places the public key into a form on the website which gets stored in the database, then the customer/user would have the private key to decrypt the data. You use the public key to encrypt the data. This would mean each user/customer would have their own set of keys. The Private key could possibly be even placed on a keycard and hooked to the computer to verify access.

More information @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Comment: By splitting up the key you mean [secret sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing), right?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to have the PHP script call an external script (doesn't necessarily have to be another PHP script; it could be anything) that would have access to the key.  As long as no one has write access to the external script, or read access to it if you hard-code the key into it, then it should be relatively secure.  If you store the key in a separate file, that file needs to be readable/writable only by the owner of the external script.

Answer (score 0):

You could encrypt/decrypt with certificates and have the server request a password for the certificate upon bootup.

The good thing is that your key is only in memory and can be different for every installation/server.

However, this method is quite a pain and generally only works when you have your own system administrators/are not dependent on a third-party hosting provider.

---

The intermediate solution to generate an encryption key per section/user/client in your database and encrypt the sensitive data with this per client key. These per-client keys are encrypted with a master key and stored in your database, while the master-key is stored somewhere in on disk with  minimal priviliges.
This will not safe you when your server gets fully compromised, but does limit the risk in case of -for example- a data-leak/partial compromise.

<sub>If the problem is you don't trust a) the programmer or b) the system administrator, you are out of luck.</sub>